# Python 3: Any tips on coding with multiple source files?

Tags: python-3.x

I am slowly starting a project that will be using multiple source files and I'm wondering what are some good practices whilst doing that. Any tips and/or tricks would be appreciated!

Comment: This question is quite broad. Did you at least read the official tutorial's section on [modules](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/modules.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Make a module. Use a versioning control system. That's it really. Otherwise best practices are the same no matter how many files you have.